# Conversion to Dalvik format failed eclipse android-suport-v4.jar error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jar

### Building the Schildbash Wallet in Eclipse

- windows 7
- wallet 3.53
- action-bar-sherlock 4.1.0
- maven 3.0.5
- ant 1.9.4
- eclipse kepler

When I run a clean build in eclipse I get [this awesome jar issue](http://s228.photobucket.com/user/blondie420_photo/media/forwhhhhy2_zps4a39cfe2.png.html):

Console Log: 
[2014-07-24 12:54:42 - wallet] Dx trouble writing output: already prepared 
[2014-07-24 12:54:43 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/_ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;
[2014-07-24 12:54:43 - wallet] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/_ActionBarSherlockTrojanHorse$OnCreateOptionsMenuListener;

I've tried unchecking the .jar library in the [java build path](http://s228.photobucket.com/user/blondie420_photo/media/xxx_zps8548f720.jpg.html) of the wallet, and tinkering with my android-suport-v4.jar file. I've tried deleteing my livbs folder in the action sidebar but that didn't work either. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Posting your POM maybe help resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to deploy using Eclipse ("Run as...")? I think that doesn't work, at least I have given up on it a while ago. Use Maven for compiling and deploying. Eclipse should be able to tell about errors though.